# Is it possible to have different buttons corrosponding to different columns of a data table without changing the row?

Tags: vue.js, button, datatable

I would like to have a row of buttons where each one adds the current time to a data table, but I am not sure if this is possible/how to do this. Does anyone have any experience doing something similar? I am working in VueJS with MySQL data tables.

Here are my buttons and the script meant to assign their values to spaces in the data table.

```js
<script>
import * as actions from "../../../Config/ApiUrl";
import { TableHelpers } from "./TableHelpers";

export default {
    name: "Biometricos",
    mixins: [TableHelpers],
    data() {
        return {
            momentInstance: moment(),
            searchValue: '',
            deleteLoader: false,
            isAddEditModalActive: false,
            deleteConformationModalActive: false,
            selectedUrl: '',
            tableId: '',
            rowData: {},
            time: null,
            isRunning: false,
            startTime: null,
            times: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            frameId: null,

            options: {
                name: 'biometricos-table',
                isAddEditModalActive: false,
                url: `${actions.BIOMETRICOS}/index`,
                showHeader: true,
                columns: [],
                datatableWrapper: false,
                showFilter: false,
                showSearch: false,
                showAction: false,
                actions: [],
                paginationType: "pagination",
                rowLimit: 10,
                orderBy: 'desc',
            },

        }
    },
    props: {
        label: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        className: {
            type: String
        },
        isDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        hours: Boolean,
        minutes: Boolean,
    },
    created() {
        this.options.columns = [...this.tableColumns];
    },
    mounted() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.momentInstance = moment()
        }, 1000)
    },
    watch: {
        searchValue: function (value) {
            if (value === '')
                this.getSearchValue();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getSearchValue() {
            this.$emit('input', this.searchValue);
        },
        submit() {
            this.$emit('submit');
        },
        currentDate() {
            return new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        },
        currentTime() {
            return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        },
        clockIn() {
            // Get the current date and time
            const currentDate = this.currentDate();
            const currentTime = this.currentTime();

            // Update the table data with the current date and time
            const newIngreso = { permission_date: currentDate, ingreso: currentTime };

            // Assuming the table data is an array under 'options' property
            this.options.data.push(newIngreso);

            // Emit an event to notify the parent component to update the table view
            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
            // Open the description modal or do other tasks as needed
            console.log('Clock In button clicked');
        },
        almorzar() {
            const currentTime = this.currentTime();

            const newAlmuerzo = { almuerzo: currentTime };

            this.options.data.push(newAlmuerzo);

            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
        },
        regresar() {
            const currentTime = this.currentTime();

            const newRegreso = { regreso: currentTime };

            this.options.data.push(newRegreso);

            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
        },
        // clockOut() {
        //     this.stop();
        //     const currentTime = this.currentTime();

        //     const newSale = { salido: currentTime };

        //     this.options.data.push(newSale);

        //     this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
        //     this.reset();
        //     // store time
        //     // store total
        //     // open description modal
        // },
        openAddEditModal() {
            this.stop();
            this.isAddEditModalActive = true;
        },
        closeAddEditModal() {
            $("#demo-add-edit-Modal").modal('hide');
            this.isAddEditModalActive = false;
            this.reSetData();
        },
        reSetData() {
            this.rowData = {};
            this.selectedUrl = '';
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<app-button :label="$t('Ingreso')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false" @click="clockIn" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Almuerzo')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click="almorzar" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Regreso')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click="regresar" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Salido')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click="openAddEditModal" />
```

Comment: If you post a bit more content we can help you, maybe add some of your code. You could make different ajax request depending on which button you press or append a hidden value to the form when each button is pressed so you know which button has been pressed when you submit your data.  You can also handle the submit with an ajax-request and append which button was pressed in the data that you post.

Comment: Why is there a PHP tag if it's a Vue question?

Comment: @mrodo I decided to include a php tag because I am working in PHP in the backend.

Comment: @Patrick thank you! have some code, let me know if you have any suggestions based on that or if more information would be helpful. In the meantime I will review ajax-requests to see if they are the solution that I am looking for.

Comment: Looks like you're already catching the click event on each button, so I would post the data from each click-function that you've created or call a function within them to post which button has been pressed. I've never worked with vue, you can use javascript fetch()

Comment: @Patrick while I am handling the click it does not appear to be registered, as my consol.log test does not display anything.